# Need to make this return statement work, how?

Tags: java, parameters, return

I am having trouble with understanding return statements.

```
public class apples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public static double slope(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

            double dy = y2 -y1;
            double dx = x2 - x1;
            return dy / dx;
        }

        slope(5, 11, 1, 3);
    }
}
```

I want to return the sum of `dy / dx`.

Comment: You can't have a method in a method in Java.

Comment: So what should I put in my main method?

Comment: Pay attention at the Java naming conventions - a class name always starts with a capital letter. You're a beginner, but it's good to get at least that from the start :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your method outside the main method :

```
public static double slope(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

    double dy = y2 - y1;
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    return dy / dx;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("slope is : " + slope(5, 11, 1, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In programming languages such as java, you can't define method inside other methods. In the above code you are defining method slope(x1,y1,x2,y2) inside main(args) method. Just move the slope() method outside main(). After that call the method from any other method, for now  call slope(1,2,3,4) from main() method. Here slope(x1,x2,y1,y2) is static method, so no need of creating an object of your class apples to refer slope() method when calling from a static method.

The method slope(x1,y1,x2,y2) is perfect. no issues with return statement.

Remember to include slope() method with in braces of the apples class. your code can be changed to the following

public class apples {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        

   double d = slope(5, 11, 1, 3);
   System.out.println("return value : " + d);
}
public static double slope(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        double dy = y2 -y1;
        double dx = x2 - x1;
        return dy / dx;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A return always quits the method. The type of the returned value must be the same as the type of the method. And you can not have a method in a method. Here you have the method slope in the method main.

Answer (score 0):

Put your slope method outside the main method but inside your apples class. Then call the slope method inside the main method.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write declaration (with argument if any)of function in main Function
like `slop(int, int,int );`

and after main method and inside the class you have to define your slop method

Hope it will help 
thanks